# Need a regular expression to match 3-member simple series

Tags: regex

I need a regex that would match the following example strings:

```
 Example 1: "red, blue, and hot"
 Example 2: "red, blue, or hot"
```

Three individual words, the first two followed by commas, and the conjunction 'and' (case 1) alternatively 'or' (case 2).

```
Case 1: "<word01>, <word02>, and <word03>"
Case 2: "<word01>, <word02>, or <word03>"
```

I have the following regex `(\w+,(\s|\n)+){2}(and|or)` that successfully matches the strings however it will also match strings where my example expressions are contained within the string.  I only want a successful match if the string contains my example expression and nothing else.

In other words `green, red, blue, and hot` should not match as it contains an additional word and comma before the match.

Comment: You can try `(\w+,(\s|\n)+){2,10}(and|or)` to match between 3 and 11 times :)

Comment: Bu that's not what i want :-) i dont want to match list with 3 and more members, but exactly 3 in total, such as "Tomas, Paul, and Eve". Longer lists should be skipped.

Comment: In fact, i dont want any ", " before the regexp, otherwise anything can be there. But mere `[^,]\s` does not work somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### REGEX Variations

I gave you a few variations depending how you want to deal with punctuation.

| RegEx ➡ | `(^\w+\,\s+\w+\,\s+(and|or)\s+\w+\Z)` |
| --- | --- |
| **Match** | **Test String** |
| ✔ | `red, blue, and hot` |
| ✗ | red, blue, and hot. |
| ✗ | green, red, blue, and hot |
| ✗ | red, blue, and hot, but not green |

| RegEx ➡ | `(^\w+\,\s+\w+\,\s+(and|or)\s+\w+\.\Z)` |
| --- | --- |
| **Match** | **Test String** |
| ✗ | red, blue, and hot |
| **✔** | `red, blue, and hot.` |
| ✗ | green, red, blue, and hot |
| ✗ | red, blue, and hot, but not green |

| RegEx ➡ | `(^\w+\,\s+\w+\,\s+(and|or)\s+\w+\.?\Z)` |
| --- | --- |
| **Match** | **Test String** |
| **✔** | `red, blue, and hot` |
| **✔** | `red, blue, and hot.` |
| ✗ | green, red, blue, and hot |
| ✗ | red, blue, and hot, but not green |

##### REGEX Used

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ^ | start of the string (position) |
| \Z | end of the string (position) |
| + | previous token > 0 times |
| ? | previous token < 2 times |
| \w | any single word character |
| \, | comma character |
| \s | whitespace character |
| | | separates alternatives (*or*) |
| \. | period character |